# Get Multiple Match Values Vertically From a Horizontal Table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I came across this formula which works well with tables which have data listed vertically, however, I am having difficulty trying to apply this to a horizontal set of data.

I tried changing the ranges etc. without any success and hope someone can help out.

Here's the formula:

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$I$5,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),
   ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$I$5,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),
   ROW(1:1)),2))}
```

The website where I found this is
[here:](http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/)

I would like to get this to work with the

[image: following sample displayed as an image:]

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,

Francis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stands to reason that changing A1:A8 to A1:H1 (rows of data into columns of data) means you also have to change the INDEX range and ROW($A$1:$A$8).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$H$2, 2, SMALL(IF($A$1:$H$1=$I$5, COLUMN($A:$H)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

The newer IFERROR reduces the code and redundant calculation.

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate your help!